# Use ScalaCheck generator inside another generator

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I have a generator that creates a very compelx object. I **cannot** create this object through something like

```
val myGen = for{
 a <- Gen.choose(-10,10)
 ...
} yield new MyClass(a,b,c,...)
```

I tried an approach of creating a custom generator like this

```
val myComplexGen :Gen[ComplexObject] = {

  ...
  val myTempVariable = Gen.choose(-10,10)
  val otherTempVal = Gen.choose(100,2000)

  new MyComplexObject(myTempVariable,otherTempVal,...)
}
```

and then

```
test("myTest") {
  forAll(myComplexGen){ complexObj => 
        ... // Here, complexObj.myTempVariable is always the same through all the iterations
 }
}
```

While this works, the values generated are always the same. The inner `Gen.choose` yield always the same value.

Is there any way I can write a custom `Gen` with its own logic, and use inner `Gen.choose` inside, that would be random ?

Comment: There's good documentation of using for-comprehension to create a case class https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/master/doc/UserGuide.md#generating-case-classes You only need to use `new` is the only difference.

Comment: The thing is, my complexObject is not a case class, it needs to be built with a builder, and other setters. It cannot be instanciated in a oneliner.

Comment: Oh, ok.  You can use curly braces after `yield` to do the building you need for `MyComplexObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to workaround the problem. The solution is definitely not elegant but that's the only way I could work it out.

I have transformed `myComplexGen` into a `def`, and called it inside another gen with dummy variables

```
def myComplexGen :ComplexObject = {

  ...
  val myTempVariable = Gen.choose(-10,10)
  val otherTempVal = Gen.choose(100,2000)

  new MyComplexObject(myTempVariable,otherTempVal,...)
}
```

---

```
val realComplexGen :Gen[ComplexObject] = for {
    i <- Gen.choose(0,10) // Not actually used, but for cannot be empty
} yield myComplexGen()
```

Now I can use `realComplexGen`in a `forAll` and the object is really random.